# What is the use of BIOS Parameter Block in a Bootloader?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I was just going about an open source boot loader and found the BIOS Parameter Block. What is the use of it? Does that mean the file system itself? Because there is a line which says "FileSystem db Fat12". I am a beginner and found this part a little hard.
Any help please..(The code was in 8086 assembly)

Comment: Just google it,  wikipedia, first two lines answer your question.  In computing, the BIOS parameter block, often shortened to BPB, is a data structure in the volume boot record describing the physical layout of a data storage volume. On partitioned devices, such as hard disks, the BPB describes the volume partition, whereas, on unpartitioned devices, such as floppy disks, it describes the entire medium.

Answer (score 3):

The BIOS Parameter Block actually has a number of uses, most of which unfortunately aren't very well defined. Its original and primary use was as a table FAT filesystem layout parameters. It's also a signature that indicates that the disk or partition uses the FAT (or HPFS or NTFS) filesystem. Finally, an often overlooked part is the media descriptor byte and other parameters that describe the physical geometry of the disk. Some BIOSes will in certain cases overwrite these parameters in the loaded boot sector in memory to inform the boot sector of an emulated geometry.

If your disk is FAT, HPFS, or NTFS formatted then you'll need an appropriately laid out and filled in BPB otherwise no operating system will be able to detect and read it.  If your disk is a physical floppy disk you might need media descriptor byte and/or the addition geometry parameters, both so the code in your boot sector can inform the BIOS of the actual geometry and other readers know what it is. Otherwise the BIOS and any other reader has to guess. If your boot sector starts with a jump instruction (or maybe certain others) the BIOS might think a BPB is present and update it.

Otherwise you don't need the BPB and can use those bytes as you wish.

Comment: While not impossible, it's not simple to put NTFS on a floppy.

Comment: @Χpẘ An NTFS BPB is necessary regardless of medium used. Key parameters like cluster size and MFT location are stored in the BPB.

Comment: I know that. But you answer implied that NTFS could be on a floppy.

Comment: @Χpẘ No, I didn't imply that. The one case where I was speaking of floppies I was specific, making a clear distinction from the more generic term "disk".

Comment: "If your disk is FAT, HPFS, or NTFS..." followed by "your disk is a physical floppy" is not a clear distinction. You use the term "your disk" in two consecutive sentences. Most readers would assume the same meaning from the same term in such close proximity.

Comment: @Χpẘ That would be an absurd interpretation. The phrase "If your disk is a physical floppy disk..."  makes a clear and obvious distinction between the word "disk" and a "physical floppy disk". The sentence only makes sense if a "physical floppy disk" is one type of a number of possible "disk" types. It doesn't make any sense to interpret as implying that a "disk" can only be a floppy. Please, if you think my post is wrong or misleading just vote accordingly. Don't waste my time with this nonsense.

Comment: If "your disk is a physical floppy disk" is equating disk and floppy under some condition. Equating and distinguishing are two very different semantic acts. If you don't want to respond to my comments with your nonsense, then don't.